# Howto Validate External Data Source before Importing in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access Database that uses an external text file for input.

I don't trust this text file and I want to validate the contents before I import the data to avoid contaminating my database.

The data is imported from the text file via a Macro which is working perfectly fine on its own. I am trying to wrap the query that does the insert inside an "If" Program Flow block in the macro.  I am having trouble getting the condition in the `If` statement to work.

The external text file source is known as the table `UserStatistics`

I have created a query (`UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect`) that contains the following code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM UserStatistics
WHERE (((UserStatistics.[Column1])="KNOWNGOODVALUE"));
```

The `If` condition in the Macro is currently set to:

- `count (*) from [UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect] >1` but this errors out.

Everything I've tried fails with the error "cannot parse..." or "cannot find the name you entered..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

### UPDATED with list of variations I've tried:

```sql
Count([UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect])>1
-- "Access cannot find the name 'UserStatistics' 
-- you entered in the expression"
```

```sql
Count[UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect] > 1 -- cannot parse
```

```sql
count (*) [UserStatistics] >1 -- "cannot parse..."
```

```sql
Count * 
where [UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect]![User ID] = 'ABC' -- cannot parse
```

```sql
Count(select * from [UserStatistics] 
where [UserStatistics]![Column1] = 'ABC') > 1 -- cannot parse
```

### MAJOR UPDATE 2

HansUp suggested `DCount`.  If I omit the criterion part of the expression the `If` condition is now evaluating.  But the criterion part is definitely needed to acheive my goal.

```
DCount("*","UserStatistics","[UserStatistics]![Column1] = 'ABC' ")>1
DCount("*","UserStatistics","Column1 = 'ABC' ")>1
DCount("*","UserStatistics",Column1 = 'ABC' )>1
```

All of the above give an error 2001

### Solution!

It turns out that my external text file column names contained spaces.  So the column in the criterion of the DCount statement needed to be wrapped in square brackets like so:

If `DCount("*","UserStatistics","[User ID]='KNOWNGOODVALUE'")>1` Then 
`Do my Actions here....`
Else
`MsgBox Error here...`
End If

Many Thanks to HansUp for pointing me towards `DCount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DCount()` expression in the condition.

```vba
DCount("*", "UserStatistics", "Column1='KNOWNGOODVALUE'")>1
```

That should return the same count as your query, but you don't actually need the query because you can include the source table name and the `WHERE` criterion as `DCount` options.

You can test that `DCount` expression in the Immediate window to work out the third option.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will open the Immediate window)  Try the following line there:

```vba
? DCount("*", "UserStatistics", "Column1='KNOWNGOODVALUE'")
```

Mind the quotes ... there is a set of single quotes in a string which is enclosed by double quotes.

Since the third option, the `WHERE` criterion, is the obstacle, use the query with `DCount` and omit the third option.

```vba
DCount("*", "[UserStatistics-CheckTxtFileIsCorrect]")
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp,  this part is now working `DCount("*","UserStatistics")>1` but I can't get the Criterion to work. It keeps giving an error 2001 which is a fairly generic error code it seems.

Comment: Success! I found that my external text file has a column name with a space in it. So the final DCount statement is `DCount("*","UserStatistics","[Column with Spaces]='KNOWNGOODVALUE'")>1` Many Thanks for your help!